# Is it possible to use not only status bar but the footer navigation view also for background image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

I have searched everywhere but didn't get any help. I want to use a background image as full screen which will cover `status bar` and the `footer navigation` also which having a `back button` with `home button` and a `task switcher button`.

**Like below image:**

[image: Nexus 5 Home Screen]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transparent *navigation bar* work for Android 4.4+ (API 19) (just like *status bar*).

**values/styles.xml**

```
<style name="FullScreenEffectTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- ... -->
</style>
```

**values-v19/styles.xml**

```
<style name="FullScreenEffectTheme">
    <!-- StatusBar -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <!-- NavigationBar -->
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

**In code** set flags:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
         View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN |
         View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
}
```

Don't forget to set this style to activity :)

Then you need to add padding or [Space](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space.html) to your layout.

**Important:** If you want to have ***landscape orientation for phones*** translucent navigation bar cause ugly issue and in this case you ***should off this feature***. I solved it like Tanner Perrien explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20795041/4198824).

Comment: I have got the background image in navigation bar by your method but the problem is there is a transparent black bar at footer how can i remove that also which you can't see in the image i have posted

Comment: Check now. Note that I removed two of style's item.